# SQL - GROUP BY Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table in which I needed the latest 2 rows from each `type` of records. using `GROUP BY`.

For example, from the picture below, what I want is to get last 2 records depending `date` column from each `page` type. I know `GROUP BY` will be used but I am not quite familiar with that.. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Group by will not work for this case. You will need something like Yogesh's solution.

Comment: i've used and got following error 
#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Time to upgrade.  How old of a MySQL that it doesn't support all those basic features?

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: i think it's 4.7.7 @nicolasl

Comment: i can't upgrade this @Eric ..

Comment: database is on live server now.. can I upgrade this without removing my data ? @Eric

Comment: @Coffee You'll have to read the documentation.  I'm not familiar with MySQL.

Comment: How many different types of "page" do yo have?

Comment: could be 4,5 types

Comment: @Coffee can you check if sessions variables work on your server version ? If they work, I can give it a try. Try: `set @a := 10; select @a;` and let me know if you get a result

Comment: take a look at the solution I've posted, hope it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, once you have so little different types, you could use an UNION aproach:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE page = 'sometype' ORDER BY date limit 2) t
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE page = 'someothertype' ORDER BY date limit 2) t
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE page = 'otherothertype' ORDER BY date limit 2) t
...
```

Just repeat this for each "page" type you have.

If this solution doesn't fits you, take a look at this article: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group

Cheers

Nikao

Comment: Great ! just add (ORDER BY date DESC limit 2) . and it is giving the expected results.. Thanks alot.

Comment: I overread the "latest" part of your question. Will update the answer ;) glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery with `limit` clause :

```
select t.*
from table t
where id in (select t1.id
             from table t1
             where t1.page = t.page
             order by t1.date desc
             limit 2
            );
```

However, only `GROUP BY` would not sufficient to do this you might need `JOIN`.

Comment: i got this error : #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Answer (score 0):

you can use row_number window function if your mysql version 8+ but if below then you may use below method of generating row number

```
set @num := 0, @page:= '';

select x.*
from (
   select t.*,
      @num := if(@page= page, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @page:= page as d
  from table t
  order by date desc
) as x where x.row_number <= 2;
```

Comment: @Coffee please share your expected output

Comment: It should show only 2 rows for each page name.. last 2 rows (with highest date, and one date less than highest )
2 rows from blog, 2 rows from events, 2 rows from gallery

Answer (score 0):

You can't use just GROUP BY to get the result you want.
You can only do that with subqueries and GROUP_CONCAT. See this:
[Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

If your MySQL version doesn't support these features you will need a different approach:

1. Get a list of all the different page types: `SELECT DISTINCT page;`
2. Programmatically iterate over the list of page types and `SELECT ... LIMIT 2;` from the main table

You should be aware that these two approaches might have very different performance if you have a huge database.